# Create simple hello world model

Tags: magento-1.9, model

I developed a extension. Now I try to add a model which has a function that returns "hello world".

I tried it like seen [here](https://www.codexpedia.com/magento/create-a-simple-model-class-in-magento/).

**app/code/local/Fekete/Newsletter2Go/etc/config.xml**

```
...
<global>
    <models>
        <fekete_newsletter2go>
            <class>Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model</class>
        </fekete_newsletter2go>
    </models>
...
```

**app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Model\Utilities\Hello.php**

```
<?php
class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model_Utilities_Hello
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

**Call:**

```
echo Mage::getModel("fekete_newsletter2go/Utilities_Hello")->hello();
```

But it does not work, I executed this in a template and the site does not fully load anymore after inserting the code.

I get:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function hello() on boolean in
>   ...app/design/frontend/base/default/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/partials/unsubscribe/form.phtml
>   on line 28

Where is the mistake?

---

**Full config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Fekete_Newsletter2Go>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Fekete_Newsletter2Go>
    </modules>
    <default>
        <newsletter2go_options>
            <!-- Standard Werte für die Extension festlegen -->
            <general>
                <is_active>0</is_active>
                <max_subscriptions>5</max_subscriptions>
            </general>

            <subscribe_text>
                <success>Sie haben sich erfolgreich angemeldet.</success>
                <error>Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Daten.</error>
                <invitation_fail>Ihre Abonnementeinladung ist abgelaufen. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.</invitation_fail>
                <double_opt_in>Vielen Dank für die Anmeldung. Wir haben Ihnen eine E-Mail mit einem Bestätigungslink zugeschickt.</double_opt_in>
                <already_subscribed>Sie sind bereits angemeldet.</already_subscribed>
                <invalid_email>Bitte tragen Sie eine gültige E-Mail Adresse ein.</invalid_email>
            </subscribe_text>

            <unsubscribe_text>
                <success>Sie haben sich erfolgreich abgemeldet.</success>
                <error>Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Daten.</error>
            </unsubscribe_text>

            <user_backend>
                <description>Sie sind mit folgenden E-Mail Adressen am Newsletter angemeldet:</description>
                <subscribe_text>Anmelden</subscribe_text>
                <unsubscribe_text>Abmelden</unsubscribe_text>
            </user_backend>
        </newsletter2go_options>
    </default>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <fekete_newsletter2go>
                <class>Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Helper</class>
            </fekete_newsletter2go>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <fekete_newsletter2go>
                <class>Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Block</class>
            </fekete_newsletter2go>
        </blocks>
        <models>
            <fekete_newsletter2go>
                <class>Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model</class>
            </fekete_newsletter2go>
        </models>

        <!-- Neues Attribut für das Customer Model -->
        <resources>
            <Fekete_Newsletter2Go_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Fekete_Newsletter2Go</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </Fekete_Newsletter2Go_setup>
            <Fekete_Newsletter2Go_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </Fekete_Newsletter2Go_write>
            <Fekete_Newsletter2Go_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </Fekete_Newsletter2Go_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <fekete_newsletter2go>
                    <file>fekete/newsletter2go.xml</file>
                </fekete_newsletter2go>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <routers>
            <fekete_newsletter2go_route>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Fekete_Newsletter2Go</module>
                    <frontName>fekete_newsletter2go</frontName>
                </args>
            </fekete_newsletter2go_route>
        </routers>  
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <newsletter2go_options>
                                            <title>Custom Configuration Section</title>
                                        </newsletter2go_options>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share your full `config.xml`

Comment: @PRINCE, see updated post.

Comment: Ok, does your module works well without that model ?

Comment: @PRINCE, yes it does work perfectly fine without it.

Comment: Code looks ok. Any typos in class or file names?

Comment: Please add template file.

Comment: @sv3n, the template file is just the output `<?php echo Mage::getModel("fekete_newsletter2go/Utilities_Hello")->hello();`
You can see all file names and classes in my post, judge yourselv if there are any typos please.

Answer (score 0):

In **app\code\local\Fekete\Newsletter2Go\Model\Utilities\Hello.php**, the class **`Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model_Utilities_Hello`** should extend **`Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`**.

That means, your code:

```
class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model_Utilities_Hello
```

should be:

```
class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model_Utilities_Hello extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
```

Comment: I tried it, but the error stays the same.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/local/Fekete/Newsletter2Go/Model/Utilities/Hello.php

```
<?php
class Fekete_Newsletter2Go_Model_Utilities_Hello extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function hello()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

Now in your **template** : (put it in your `current theme` instead `base`).

> app/design/frontend/{yourTheme}/{themeName}/template/fekete/Newsletter2Go/partials/unsubscribe/form.phtml

```
<?php $hello = Mage::getModel("fekete_newsletter2go/utilities_hello")->hello(); ?>
<?php echo $hello; ?>
```

Clean cache.

Comment: No. `Mage::getModel()` and other business logic doesn't belong to template files. You know better when to use blocks :)

Comment: @sv3n is back :) Yes It is better to use a block exemple: `$this->->hello()`  in templates but he want a model, And why `No`  ? we can use a model in templates without problem (I know it is not a good practice), I think his object is not just to create model to say hello, but it just a test, he will use it for something else.
I'm pretty sure that you have some `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`in template in your projects ?

Comment: Missed you too :) `No` b/c it does not belong there - if its not for testing. I do not use `Mage::getModel` in templates.

Comment: Does not work either. Same error.